# htaccess - How to redirect ww. & w. subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

A friend of mine has a strange problem: His website is reachable with w.domain.com and ww.domain.com and Google has started to index these sites.

How is it to achieve, that both subdomains are redirected to www. ?
Is it the same way as normally? Like:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [nc] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Simply write 2 other RewriteConds with ^w.domain.com & ^ww.domain.com ??

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to redirect all traffic to www.domain.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP} !^www\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```